# Placing Ads in Android

Tags: android, layout, admob

Firstly what views should I use in order to be able to add ads like [this](http://phandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/ad-clicks-accidental-small.png.pagespeed.ce_.7SsVPkAqEA.png) (angry birds).

Secondly how do I add the views in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends which ad provider you use, but many people use AdMob, and their SDK instructions are here. AdMob is very easy to implement.

AdMob:
http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android#App_Integration

Google AdSense
http://www.google.com/mobileads/publisher_home.html

You may also want to look at http://helpcenter.adwhirl.com/ which is a free tool to auto-rotate between Admob and other ad providers, and may help you get a better deal.

Ultimately which one works best for you is likely to be down to trial and error, but luckily they are easy to integrate and swap around.

Answer (score 0):

Angry Birds uses [AdMob](http://www.admob.com/) Contact them for more details (they send you the SDK, examples and [documentation](http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android#App_Integration)).